# Python. Making a function that tests if a word is a palindrome recursively

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that tests if a word is a palindrome using a recursive function. I pretty much have it working but I'm just having trouble with getting it to move on to the next letter if the first and last are the same.

```
word = input("enterword")
word = word.lower()

def palindrom(word):
    if len(word) == 1 or len(word) == 0:
        return 0;
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        print(word[0], word[-1])
        palindrom(word);
    else:
        return 1;

test = palindrom(word)
if test == 0:
    print("Yes")
elif test == 1:
    print("No")
```

So right now it tests if the first and last letter are the same and if so, should run the function again. I just need to have it then check word[1] and word[-2] but I'm having some trouble. I tried splitting word and just popping the letters but it kept looking at the list as a length of 1. So if there is a way to get it to get the length of the whole split list, that would work as well.

Comment: Awww, come on. There are dozens of questions about the exact same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952110/recursive-function-palindrome-in-python?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666339/python-and-palindromes?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769890/performance-of-various-methods-to-test-for-a-palindrome-python?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing the return statement when you call your method recursively and the correct slice:

```
def palindrom(word):
    if len(word) == 1 or len(word) == 0:
        return 0
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        print(word[0], word[-1])
        return palindrom(word[1:-1])
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: Just to confirm. Does word[1:-1] increment it by that each time rather than telling it what position to read?

Comment: `word[1:-1]` returns the section of the word from position 1 to the penultimate letter. I.e. "*racecar*" becomes "*aceca*."

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2676531) for a good explanation.

Comment: Ohh duh. Now I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return statement, also you need to pass reduced word `palindrom(word[1:-1])` on each recursion.

```
word = "viooiv"
word = word.lower()


def palindrom(word):
    if len(word) == 1 or len(word) == 0:
        return 0 
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        print(word[0], word[-1])
        return palindrom(word[1:-1])
    else:
       return 1 

test = palindrom(word)
if test == 0:
    print("Yes")
elif test == 1:
    print("No"
```

Output:

```
 ('v', 'v')
 ('i', 'i')
 ('o', 'o')
 Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling palindrome on the word with this function:

```
def palindrome(word, i = 0):
    if i == len(word):
        return word[0] == word[-1]

    if word[i] == word[-i - 1]:
        return palindrome(word, i + 1)

    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more shorter code:

```
def checkpalindrome(value):
    valuelen = len(value)
    if valuelen < 2:
        print("palindrome")
    else:
        checkpalindrome(value[1:valuelen-1]) if value[0] == value[-1] else print('Not palindrome')
```